# Is there an HTML/CSS only solution (no scripting) to creating hidden iframes that don't load until they become visible?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am directed to create one or more divs on a page containing iframe(s) that default to display:none.

1. When the div becomes visible, the iframe can play a YouTube video
   on a specific topic.
2. The link that makes an iframe div visible is an item from a list of
   possible topics.
3. The video "window" is supposed to open in the position where the
   link text was.

I know I can do this with one video on a page, and the impact on page load time is minimal. But what if there are thirty topics in the list? Do I need to create a window in the appropriate position for each one?

And if I do, do all thirty videos load when the page loads, even though the divs and iframes are all hidden?

What I most need to know is **whether or not** there is an HTML/CSS solution for a page with this many potential videos that does not involve a script and does not result in a major impact on the page loading time.

It sounds from the other answers I've read as though the good solutions to appearing/disappearing video "windows" like this all involve scripts (either Javascript or something else beyond HTML/CSS).

Comment: can you rephrase the question, maybe? I'm unsure of whether you want the div to show when the iframe has loaded or something else. A jsfiddle or codepen would be good.

Comment: The short answer is no.  Not without a script..

Comment: Thanks. No, the divs default to display:none, and clicking on the link makes that specific div display on screen. What I would *like* to have happen is that the video does not load till the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get the effect you're after using iframes without any scripts...

On the other hand if you can get away with using the html5 video tag rather than iframes you may be able to pull it off.

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
li video {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
li:hover video {
  height: 150px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hover me!
    <video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" preload="none" controls>Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.</video>
  </li>
  <li>Hover Me!
    <video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" preload="none" controls>Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.</video>
  </li>
  <li>Hover Me!
    <video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" preload="none" controls>Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.</video>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using `preload="none"` on the videos should prevent the videos from loading before the user presses play. The obvious downside is that the user may have to wait a few seconds for the video to buffer after pressing play, but without using any scripts this may be your least bad option.

Comment: Thanks -- where would I put the preload="none" ? Does it go in the CSS for li video?

Comment: @Chris I don't think you can apply preload in css, its an attribute not a property, so I think you'll have to put it on the video tag directly like it is in the example. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HTML and CSS only, then you need to create a 'window in the appropriate position for each one', as you asked.

Yes, that would greatly affect the page's load time, so it would be best to use Javascript to dynamically load all of your video content.

It sounds like you don't know any JS and are afraid to even learn it, but a script that performs what you want would be easy. I say you give it a shot. Besides, JS goes hand-in-hand with HTML and CSS. Might as well learn it now.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not afraid of Javascript ;) but have been directed not to use any on this project because it's being migrated to a different CMS.

Comment: Is this for a client?

Comment: No, it's how my supervisor told me to do this project. The CMS we will be moving this page into very shortly has no option for using in-page scripts at this point. (It will, but that's months down the road.)